# Нужно ли проверять URl на инъекции в этом случае? Eсли да, то как?

Tags: url, php

Нужно ли проверять `$_GET['x']` и как правильно ее проверить?

```
header('Location: '.$_GET['x']);
exit();
```

Answer (score 4):

Проверь что это корректный url и все

Comment: Тоесть регулярками ,которые определяют ,что это действительно URL?

Comment: Либо так либо php-функциями для работы с url.
parse_url() и т.п.